# Parse html td is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code and the parseFloat will not work. It returns NaN. Any ideas! The value variable return the string (which is a number), but the problem is in the parsed variable: var pv = parseFloat(value);. pv returning NaN.

The html table:

```
var Er1 = '<div><table Id="AEid" width="85%" border="3"><tbody>' +
'<tr><th><b>AM1</b></th><th><b>AM2</b></th><th><b>Total</b></th></tr>' +
'<tr><td >2</td><td rowspan="1">3</td><td rowspan="1"></td></tr>' +
'<tr><td rowspan="1"></td><td rowspan="1"></td><td rowspan="1"></td></tr>' +
'</tbody></table></div>';

//-------------

$newDiv = $(Er1);
var rows = $newDiv.find('tr')
rows.each(function (idx, item) {
    if (idx > 0) {
        var sum = 0;
        var cols = $(item).children('td')
        for(var i=0;i<cols.length -1;i++){        
        var value = $(cols[i]).text();
        value = value.trim();
        var pv = parseFloat(value);        
        sum = sum + pv; 
        alert("i: " + i +"\n Value: " + value +"\n sum: " + sum + "\n parsedValue: " + pv);                 
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your value is empty string in some cases

Comment: can you create a fiddle ,Use **jquery ready** , maybe **DOM** is not charged when you call this function

Comment: @Charafjra: Getting `NaN` as the result has nothing to do with not placing the code in a `$()` call.

Comment: Why is your `each` not closed (no `)` at end)?

Comment: Is your variable Er1 already written to the DOM when you execute your .find and .each functions?

Comment: I have the closing code! also this is just inside the var (js). I write it back to sharepoint rich text area where my table is. but I can see a number value for the value in the alert box, but not for parsed value: pv. any other thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
var cols = $(item).children('td');
```

to

```
var cols = $(item).children('td:not(:empty)');
```

Or you may also do,

```
value = value.trim();
if(value == "") value = 0;
```

Comment: Specifically, it is this item which gives NaN when you try to parseInt it: `<td rowspan="1"></td>`

Comment: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN.

Comment: value is not empty, I see the number in the alert box.

Comment: TML: correct the problem is here: rowspan="1". So how do I parse a number from here: <td rowspan="1">55</td>?

Comment: TML: can you put your comments in its own to accept it. Also I have work around the problem, but if you have any answer to my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

This because : parseFloat('') => NaN;

Just modify this line of code : var pv = parseFloat(value);

by this one : var pv = (value!='') ? parseFloat(value) : 0;

Comment: value is not empty, I can see the number in the alert box

Answer (score 0):

It returns NaN because when you parse the `td`, it returns an empty string.  [In my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/7VxBE/1/) you can see a simple conditional statement that checks if there is no value, to assign it a value of 0.

```
if (!value) value = 0;
```

Comment: value is not empty, I can see the number in the alert box. Also this will set value to 0 which is something I don't won't.